# Outlook Application - Can't get the list of folders

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop, directory

I've created a little program to save my emails to a Windows Folder.

I can't retreive the list of outlook folders.

When I check if I've selected the inbox folder, it's not!

```
Dim app As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim siFolder As Outlook.Folder

Dim Annee As Integer
Dim Mois As Integer
Dim Jour As Integer

app = New Outlook.Application()
ns = app.Session

siFolder = CType(ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox), Outlook.Folder) 'I select here the Inbox Folder

' I do a test, but siFolder.name appears not to be the inbox folder !!

If siFolder.Name Is ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) Then
   Annee = Format(mailitem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy")
   Mois = Format(mailitem.ReceivedTime, "MM")
   Jour = Format(mailitem.ReceivedTime, "dd")
ElseIf siFolder Is ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) Then
   Annee = Format(mailitem.SentOn, "yyyy")
   Mois = Format(mailitem.SentOn, "MM")
   Jour = Format(mailitem.SentOn, "dd")
Else
   MsgBox("Aucune boite sélectionnée")
   End 'because i can't select the Inbox, application ends here.
End If
```

Comment: Don't you need to use the 'Set' keyword when creating an object reference in VB.NET? It should be '**Set** app = New Outlook.Application' and '**Set** ns = app.Session'

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote a while ago. It adds the folders to a treeview:

```
Public Sub startTreeviewBuild()

    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application()
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing

    oNS.Logon("Outlook", "", False, True)
    'oNS.Session.AddStore("C:\pstfile.pst")' uncomment to point to a pst file
    objFolder = oNS.Session.Folders.GetLast()

    TreeView1.Visible = False
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(objFolder.Name)
    buildPSTTreeview(objFolder, TreeView1.Nodes(0))
    TreeView1.Visible = True

End Sub

Public Sub buildPSTTreeview(ByVal StartFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, ByVal parentnode As TreeNode)
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem = Nothing

    For i = 1 To StartFolder.Items.Count
        objItem = StartFolder.Items.Item(i)
        If TryCast(objItem, Outlook.MailItem) IsNot Nothing Then
            mailItem = DirectCast(objItem, Outlook.MailItem)
            If mailItem.Subject = Nothing Then
                parentnode.Nodes.Add(mailItem.EntryID)
            Else
                parentnode.Nodes.Add(mailItem.Subject.ToString)
            End If

        End If
    Next

    ' process all the subfolders of this folder
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
    For i = 1 To StartFolder.Folders.Count
        objFolder = StartFolder.Folders.Item(i)
        Dim myNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(objFolder.Name)
        parentnode.Nodes.Add(myNode)
        'objFolder.Name
        Application.DoEvents()
        Call buildPSTTreeview(objFolder, myNode)
    Next
    objFolder = Nothing
    objItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

It may not be perfect, butit worked for me :-)

Comment: Thanks David,

This was very helpful.
Could you tell me if there's a way to :
1.- Select Only the folders which contains Emails (not contacts, calendar, Tasks, ...) to populate the treeview ?
2.- Select other personal folders ou folders like xxx@live.fr (xxx@live.fr contains too some folders like : inbox, sentitems, ...).

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @joran : Hello Joran, have you a solution for selecting folders in Outlook and populate a treeview ? (personal folders, archive folders, ...) ? Thanks